# Data isn't showing Angular8 (Metronic Theme)

Tags: angular, angular8, metronic

When im using this in my html `{{user.firstName}}` the data is showing but with errors but when i use this  in my html `{{user?.firstName}}` the data isnt displaying but no errors but when i click a button, the data is showing. Hello guys im using metronic and angular8

Do you have alternative guys on how to display data?

```
import { Component, OnInit, enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";
import { DealerapiService } from "../services/dealerapi.service";
import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
    selector: "kt-home-profile",
    templateUrl: "./home-profile.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./home-profile.component.scss"]
})
export class HomeProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private dealerApiService: DealerapiService,
        private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}
    forms: any;
    profileForm: FormGroup;
    imageurl: any;
    username: any;
    user: any;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            // get the username out of the route params
            this.username = params["username"];

            const username = params["username"];
            this.dealerApiService
                .getUserbyUsernameProfile(username)
                .subscribe((user: any) => {
                    this.user = user.data;
                    console.log(user);
                });
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you add some punctuation to your post? I have no idea what you're trying to say.

Comment: Can you add the HTML snippet

Comment: {{ user?.firstName }} this is the only code in my html

Comment: what errors you are getting?

Comment: And the button?

Comment: "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer]" This is the error when i remove the "?" in {{user?.firstName}}

Comment: Your html gets renders before user get a response. So you are getting this error. Try {{user?user.firstName:''}} OR you can add  *ngIf="user" to your template with {{user.firstname}}. It will resolve errors

Comment: i've tried that. it shows no error but the data is not displaying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This exactly is my problem.... Metronic theme is not rendering received data from API to the template..
It renders the received data after Emitting an event.
So, you can bind the click function to any already rendered button..

Document.getElementById('alreadyRenderedBTN').click();

...
Or simply change the **ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush**
To
**ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default**

Inside **app.component.ts**

Comment: Thank you so god damn much <3

Answer (score 1):

Try like below,

```
export class HomeProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  ...
  ...
  user: any; // comment this line
  user = <User>{}; // Add this line

  ...
  ...
}

// Add the below model after your component class
export class User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  // remaining properties
}
```

Now in your html, you can access the user property without ? (safe operator)

```
{{user.firstName}}
```

Comment: In your service call, console.log(this.user); -> can you post this console result here.

Comment: """{message: "Get Dealer successful by Public", data: {…}, imageData: {…}}message: "Get Dealer successful by Public"data: firstName: "Ryan"lastName: "zxczz"userName: "fxxdmin"email: "arquezaryan@gmail.com"contactNumber: "09055555222"address: "ph"onlineStore: "asddsasadads"uploadFile: "5e14215dcc53323714bfe4ce"__proto__: ObjectimageData: {type: "Buffer", data: Array(52722)}__proto__: Object"""

Comment: the above data doesn't look like properly formatted JSON data

Comment: It's properly formatted JSON but, i think the problem is metronic theme.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign user's firstname value in the component file itself.
Try this:

```
firstName: string;
// other variables

// ..other code..

this.dealerApiService
  .getUserbyUsernameProfile(username)
     .subscribe((user: any) => {
        this.user = user.data;
        // added code
        this.firstname = user['data']['firstName'];
        console.log(user);
      });
   });
```

Now try to access the firstName from your template.

Comment: it still doesn't show i dunno why, but when i click a button the data displays.

Comment: I didn't understand, exactly what are you trying to say?